# How to generate custom widths for bootstrap classes using SASS

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I want to customize the bootstrap source code so that I get more **w-XX** classes. I want to extend it so that I have both **w-40** and **w-60**. I see in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) that I have to modify the **$sizes** variable.

So in my custom.scss I do just that:

```
$sizes: (
    25: 25%,
    40: 40%,
    50: 50%,
    60: 60%,
    75: 75%,
    100: 100%,
    auto: auto
);
```

And then I compile my scss file but the new classes I want are not generated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `bootstrap.scss` after it.

```
$sizes: (
    25: 25%,
    40: 40%,
    50: 50%,
    60: 60%,
    75: 75%,
    100: 100%,
    auto: auto
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: Thanks. How come the import doesn't overwrite the variables?

Comment: specified variables are overwrite in this